# HTML form: print a php result

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to create a form that show a table obtain from a databse. I am following the tutorial about AJAX from the w3school and let me give my example:

I have a php file that print a table as a result of a database request with two variable x and y. If I put in my favorite navigator: localhost/list.php?x=0&y=0 it print a nice table... But what I want is to obtain x and y by a form I write more or less as in the turorial a index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function loadList() {
  var xhttp;    
  var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "list.php?x="+x+"&y="+y, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="x"> <br> 
    <input type="text" id="y"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Find" onclick="loadList()">
</form>

<div id="table"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like that my form write the result (forexample when x=0 and y=0) of the list.php file in the div="table" at the end after the form! But... It does not works and I cannot resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: What is your code for list.php?

Comment: Print_r($_REQUEST); ???

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear, what exactly you want?

Comment: @user5697101: the code for list.php use $_GET method, it works fine as a standalone file (there is no html tag etc it is just a <?php ... php> file which connect to a database and print a table.

Comment: @devpro: print_r($_REQUEST); I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @mikelee: I just want the form makes: if I put the value of x and y in the form it returns the table in the last div, obtain by list.php?x=..&y=..

Comment: R u getting values in php file ?? Chk it

Comment: Yes I am getting value as I mention, in particular: localhost/list.phplist.php?x=..&y=..  where .. are values works well

Comment: I change my php file for a simple one, namely:
<?php
$x = (int)$_GET['x'];
$y = (int)$_GET['y'];

echo "$x , $y";
?>
 And I have still nothing

Comment: It works fine on my computer. Can you execute the PHP script on your computer? If you inspect your HTML form in Chrome (using F12), do you see any error?

Comment: @Kevin. Shame on me!!! I pass half of the day because it was written liste.php in my code and list.php for the file... your hint allows me to find the rror. I was not aware on this html inspector! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: No problem :), I'm glad it worked out for you.